# Prove that for a bilinear symmetric form $B$ there's a vector v$≠$0 that B(v,v)=0 iff $B$ and $-B$ are not positive

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

a bit of a messy question:

Suppose there's a Bilinear symmetric form $B$ on vector space $V$ above $R$.

how can I prove that there's a $v ∈ V$ that sustains $B(v,v)=0$ iff $B$ and $-B$ are not positive?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $u\in V$ set $q(u):=B(u,u)$.

The "$\Rightarrow$" follows directly from definition of positive bilinear form.

For "$\Leftarrow$" pick $u, v\in V$ such that $q(u)=B(u,u)\geq 0$ and $q(v)=B(v,v)\leq 0$. Note that $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto f(t):=q(tu+(1-t)v)$$ is a continuous map (check it! Use that $B$ is bilinear and show that this function is a quadratic polynomial in $t$). Now use the intermediate value theorem to get a zero of $f$ and conclude.

Comment: can u explain what is t?

Comment: It is a real number. We consider the function mapping the real number $t$ to $q(tu + (1-t)v)$ which is a real number again. That is why I wrote $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to indicate that the map has the reals as its domain and its codomain.